# redirect to the current page

Tags: php

What is the best way to redirect the user coming from one URL to another?

I have 2 locations.

http:mysite.com
http://public.mysite.com

I want the users who type http://mysite.com to be redirected to http://public.mysite.com
It would have been easy if there were 2 different index.php files, but the index.php file is the same in both the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On mysite.com:

```
    <?php
    $url = “http” . ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? “s” : “”) . “://”.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if($url != "http://public.mysite.com") {
       header("Location: http://public.mysite.com");
       exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Don't forget the `exit;`!

Good Luck,
Henrik

Comment: If I use echo "$url" then what is the expected output? I am not getting anything!

Comment: the expected output should be the full url of your site

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with apache's .htaccess, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://public.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try javascript which is easiest

<script>
window.location.href = "http://public.mysite.com";
</script>

Happy coding

Comment: Hmm, the problem here is that it's the same index page.